# How to use two slash division symbols in siunitx

Tags: siunitx

I would like to write 150 mT/m/ms using the package siunitx. However, I succeed only in writing mT/(m ms). How can I use two slash division symbols at once?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage{siunitx} 
\begin{document} 
\SI[per-mode=symbol]{150}{\milli\tesla\per\meter\per\milli\second}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `repeated-symbol`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage{siunitx} 
\begin{document} 
\SI[per-mode=repeated-symbol]{150}{\milli\tesla\per\meter\per\milli\second}
\end{document}
```

[image]